# Got segment fault using fgets to read file

Tags: c, gdb

I got segment fault when using fgets(). Does anyone have an idea where might be wrong? Thanks.
Here is my part of code:

```
char buf[1024]="";
char str[32];
char line[32];

in = fopen(argv[1], "r");

while(fgets (line, sizeof(line), in) != NULL){          
        zero_pad(line, str);  // padding 0s to the line
        strcat(buf, str);
        printf("\nBuffer: %s\n", buf);
}
```

Here is the zero_pad function：(It will simply look up the number of bits, if length of string smaller than number of bits, appending 0s at the front)

```
void zero_pad(char line[], char res[]){
   int num_bits, i;
   char *tmp;
   char *bin_str;
   if(line[strlen(line)-1]=='\n')  line[strlen(line)-1]='\0';
   //split by space
   tmp = strtok(line, " ");
   strcpy(bin_str, tmp);
   tmp = strtok(NULL, " ");
   num_bits = atoi(tmp);

   if(strlen(bin_str) < num_bits) {
     char t[32]="";
     for(i=0; i< (num_bits-strlen(bin_str)); i++)
          t[i] = '0';

     strcat(t, bin_str);
     strcpy(res, t);
   }
   else
     strcpy(res, line);   
}
```

In GDB, I got this error message:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI___libc_free (mem=0x7ffff7eca000) at malloc.c:2929
2929    malloc.c: No such file or directory.

(gdb) bt
#0  __GI___libc_free (mem=0x7ffff7eca000) at malloc.c:2929
#1  0x00007ffff7a8ff5e in _IO_free_backup_area (fp=0x603250) at genops.c:209
#2  __GI___uflow (fp=0x603250) at genops.c:388
#3  0x00007ffff7a83dc4 in __GI__IO_getline_info (fp=0x603250, 
    buf=0x7fffffffdf60 "1111", n=31, delim=10, extract_delim=1, eof=0x0)
    at iogetline.c:69
#4  0x00007ffff7a82d46 in _IO_fgets (buf=0x7fffffffdf60 "1111", n=0, 
    fp=0x603250) at iofgets.c:56
#5  0x0000000000400b8d in main ()
```

And I also tried ltrace.

Here are the last several lines:

```
putchar(65, 0x7fffd69cb460, 0, 0x7fa52aa5fa50)   = 65
printf("\nBuffer: %s\n", "0001000100010000000000001111"A
Buffer: 0001000100010000000000001111
) = 38
putchar(67, 0x7fffffda, 0x7fa52ad809e0, 37)      = 67
fgets( <no return ...>
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

Comment: Knowing the file actually **opened** would probably be highly advantageous. Hows about we check that before assuming `in` isn't NULL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that but still got segment fault. And the program actually can read the contents of file. Just segfault after reading the contents.

Comment: why bother initialising buffer to be "" ?

Comment: @chris `strcat(buf, str);`

Comment: in the docs it doesn't say you need to. all I'm thinking is maybe the \0 he has put in buffer is interfering with strcat.

Comment: Maybe you're overwriting `in` with the `zero_pad()` function.

Comment: zero_pad feels like it might be altering line so that it is invalid memory the next time you loop

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I have added my code in zero_pad function. It simply compare the length. If string is shorter than required length, just add 0s at the front.

Comment: You're using `bin_str` before it's initialized. Check compiler warnings.

Comment: this line: strcpy(bin_str, tmp); will crash because bin_str is only a pointer, not pointing to any specific memory.  This will result in undefined behaviour (and probably a seg fault)

Comment: this line: in = fopen(argv[1], "r"); has some problems 1) no check has been made to assure that argv[1] actually points to a string.  2) no check has been made to assure the file exists 3) no check has been made to assure that the open was successful the variable 'in' is not defined in the scope of this function as file* in = NULL;

Comment: this line: while(fgets (line, sizeof(line), in) != NULL){ has the problem that line is 32 characters and the call to fgets will try to read 32 characters, then append a '\0'  (totaling 33 characters) this is undefined behaviour (possibly leading to a seg fault).  the line should be: while(fgets (line, sizeof(line)-1, in) != NULL){

Comment: this line: num_bits = atoi(tmp); the function atoi() does NOT return a bit count, rather it converts an ascii number (a character string or numbers) to its' binary value.  I.E "123" would be converted to and int value of 123.

Comment: this line: if(strlen(bin_str) < num_bits) { is meaningless as your comparing a converted value extracted from the first token extracted from the string to the length of a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
void zero_pad(char line[], char res[]){
   int num_bits, i;
   char *tmp;
   char *bin_str;
   if(line[strlen(line)-1]=='\n')  line[strlen(line)-1]='\0';
   //split by space
   tmp = strtok(line, " ");
   strcpy(bin_str, tmp);
```

... your `strcpy()` is attempting to copy the contents of `tmp` to the location pointed at by *uninitialized* pointer `bin_str`.

If you are willing to assume a maximum length for words (based, maybe, on the declared array sizes in your `main()` function), then you could perhaps declare it this way instead:

```
char bin_str[32];
```